# UIImageview not showing after being added to another subview which is UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, addsubview

I am creating a view controller in code only, NO .xib or storyboard.
I have many other subviews added to the view, which are added in a method (void)loadView and their frames are initialised in the (id)init method as shown below

```
-(id)init{ 

   bottomClinkRect = CGRectMake(playersBoardRect.origin.x + (playersBoardWidth * 0.320),
                                playersBoardRect.origin.y + playersBoardHeight - playerBottomImageRect.size.height -  (playersBoardHeight * 0.038),
                                playersBoardWidth * 0.680,
                                playersBoardHeight * 0.038);
}
- (void)loadView {

   bottomClink = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:bottomClinkRect];
   [bottomClink setScrollEnabled:YES];
   bottomClink.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bottomClink.frame.size.height,bottomClink.frame.size.height);
   [contentView addSubview:bottomClink];
}
```

I create empty scrollview and then based on user actions on screen I am trying to add one imageView per time to the scrollview using the following method:

```
-(void)reloadCollections:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIImage *latestPieceCaptured = [gameController capturedBlackPiecesImages].lastObject;

    [whitePlayerCaptures addObject:latestPieceCaptured];

    NSInteger newNumberOfViews = whitePlayerCaptures.count;

    CGFloat xOrigin = (newNumberOfViews - 1) * bottomClink.frame.size.height;

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(bottomClink.frame.origin.x + xOrigin,
                                  bottomClink.frame.origin.y,
                                  bottomClink.frame.size.height, //the width is taken from the height
                                  bottomClink.frame.size.height); // the height

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
    image.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    image.image = latestPieceCaptured;
    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    //set the scroll view content size
    bottomClink.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bottomClink.frame.size.height * newNumberOfViews,
                                         bottomClink.frame.size.height);

    [bottomClink  addSubview:image];
}
```

My problem is that the `scrollview` is added to the main `view` but the `imageview`(s) are not showing up.

I have debugged it and the `scrollview` has the subviews added and they have frame size and all, but not showing on the screen. I have tried so many variations but nothing has worked so far.

Thanks in advance for any links or advice.

Answer (score 1):

That works for me:

```
- (void)addImagesToScrollView {

    [self.scrollViewOutlet setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];

    _scrollViewOutlet.delegate = self;

    for (int i = 0; i < thumbnailPreview.count; i++) {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.scrollViewOutlet.frame.size.width;
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0,
                                         self.scrollViewOutlet.frame.size.width,
                                         self.scrollViewOutlet.frame.size.height)];
        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed: [thumbnailPreview objectAtIndex:i]];

            image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;


       image.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;


        image.clipsToBounds = YES;

        [self.scrollViewOutlet addSubview:image];
    }
    //set the scroll view content size
    self.scrollViewOutlet.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollViewOutlet.frame.size.width *
                                                   thumbnailPreview.count,
                                                   self.scrollViewOutlet.frame.size.height);

}
```

And call it in

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: it does not work for me! I have tried your code but nothing appears in the actual scrollview it doesnt even give me any error as the imageviews are added to the scrollview but are not visible

Comment: also I am trying to add images there on demand and not when viewloads or any starting position that's why I have added observer for this method to be called when certain conditions are met.

Comment: Check if you add images in Assets.xcassets or bundle.

Comment: I have the images and when I put a breakpoint in the above function and hover the mouse over the image then click on the eye icon in the dropdown, I see the actual image.